# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/EventZone/register/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

Im in a middle of a SpringMVC project and I have encountered a "no mapping found" error.

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />    


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

controller class:

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/EventZone/register/")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getRegisterPage(){

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("RegisterViews/register");


        return model;
    }
}
```

Im trying every solution I can find but none seems to work.

Comment: What is the complete URL that you are trying to hit? Also include your webcontext.

Comment: URL is http://localhost:8040/EventZone/register/
What do you mean by "include webcontext"?

Comment: Usually you will hit url of pattern `localhost:8040/{webcontext}/EventZone/register`. I see you are missing webcontext. What is your webcontext?

Answer (score 0):

yes i.e what you were missing no need of extra logic you need to add wecontext means your application name like. http://localhost:8080/SpringMVN/EventZone/register/
tell me how you are deploying  your application. and at last add the '/' you are missing that because you given at requestmapping in your controller class.